# Python - Is there a specific method for creating custom dimension using GA4 admin api?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to automate GA4 administrative tasks using this GitHub rep: https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-admin/tree/main/samples

However, there's no method in this repository to create custom dimensions. Though the API documentation supports the creation of custom dimension.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.customDimensions/create

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Samples for the newly released API methods will be added shortly. Here is a snippet using the `properties.customDimensions.create` method:

```
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient
from google.analytics.admin_v1alpha import CustomDimension

property_id = "YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient()
custom_dimension = client.create_custom_dimension(
    parent=f"properties/{property_id}",
    custom_dimension=CustomDimension(
        parameter_name="test_dimension",
        display_name="Test Dimension",
        description="This is a test custom dimension.",
        scope=CustomDimension.DimensionScope.EVENT,
    ),
)

print("Result")
print(f"Resource name: {custom_dimension.name}")
print(f"Parameter name: {custom_dimension.parameter_name}")
print(f"Display name: {custom_dimension.display_name}")
print(f"Description: {custom_dimension.description}")
print(f"Scope: {CustomDimension.DimensionScope(custom_dimension.scope).name}")
print(
    f"Disallow Ads Personalization: {custom_dimension.disallow_ads_personalization}"
)
```